# How to import images from CSV and attach to model with ActiveStorage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, rake-task, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to import users avatar from a CSV and attach to the users with ActiveStorage.

I've created a rake task for this, but it's not working (and do not throws any error). In my CSV there are only 2 fields: email and avatar (avatar is the url to the file, that is on another server).

This is the task:

```
require 'csv'
namespace :import do
  desc "Import avatars to users from CSV"
  task avatars: :environment do
    filename = File.join Rails.root, "avatars.csv"

    CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true, col_sep: ";", header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
      User.find_by(email: row[:email]) do |u|
        u.avatar.attach(URI.parse(row[:avatar]).open)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Any advice?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to catch the any exception and print the problem in the console?

Something like that:

```rb
require 'csv'
namespace :import do
  desc "Import avatars to users from CSV"
  task avatars: :environment do
    begin
      filename = File.join Rails.root, "avatars.csv"

      CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true, col_sep: ";", header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
        User.find_by(email: row[:email]) do |u|
          u.avatar.attach(URI.parse(row[:avatar]).open)
        end
      end
    rescue StandardError => e
      logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
      logger.error e.message
      logger.error e.backtrace.join("\n")
    end
  end
end
```

Also, are you sure you have users with that email?

Comment: Hi @mariotux. No errors with the code you provided, and yes, there are users with those emails. I'm starting to think that may be a devise validation? I forgot to mention that I use devise for authentication... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I get this from the console but no error: 'irb(main):003:0> Rake::Task['import:avatars'].invoke
  User Load (15.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "email1@email.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "email2@email.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> [#<Proc:0x00007f88a66b6c10@...path.../lib/tasks/import_avatars.rake:18>]'. I've edited the path and emails, for privacy.